# Ajax : get errors form in controller and resend them with json

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I want get the error in my form but actually the return is empty.
The data is received by the controller. When I send a valid form everything is OK.

Here is my code :

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
               // This part is OK
            }
            else {

                $val = array();

                    // I get errors : 
                $val['error'] = $form->getErrors();
                echo json_encode($val);

                $response = new Response;
                $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                return $response;

            }
        }
```

I tried to add `array('error_bubbling'=>true)` in my form builder but the return don't show any fields has an error...

The function `getErrorsAsString()` returns the right result but I want it to return an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JsonResponse

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData(array(
    'data' => 123
));

return $response;
```

Comment: I replaced with your syntaxe, but still i've the same problem. The errors returning by getErrors is null.

Comment: you can try "$form->handleRequest($request);"  replace  "$form->bind($request);"

Comment: Same, it is curious that we have no simple way to get a error in the controller...

Comment: if you want to get errors from form, you just use the validator Service   [Using the validator Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service)

Comment: Oh, okay I thought we could get the errors without manually validation. I'll tell you if this solution work! Thank